# PHP Application on Azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles, paas, azure-cloud-services

I'm trying to move my PHP web application to Azure (PaaS) as a Cloud service (Webrole) using Azure SDK for PHP. Does azure cloud services have support
for "COM interop". My application interacts with a third party software for results processing. How do I install this software in the cloud service ?

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general server tech support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloud Services run on Windows Server, so as a general rule, the answer is "Yes", COM Interop is supported.

More specifically though, it is likely your PHP solution requires the installation of a component that requires COM Interop to work - you would need to automate the installation of this component as part of your deployment process [using a statup task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh180155.aspx).

As a side note, the Azure SDK for PHP is more about supporting automation and interaction with Azure services (blob storage, etc) rather than helping "port" PHP applications to Azure.  If your application runs today on Windows Server with IIS it should run on Azure Web Roles.

Comment: Thanks Simon ! I do have a follow-up question is there a better way to package my application to deploy it on azure as a cloud service ?

Comment: You're fairly limited in options because you are using PHP. Worst case you could switch to deploying to a VM which gives you full control over the server. If you really want to use a Web Role then follow the guidance here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/silverlining/archive/2012/06/21/creating-a-php-web-role-in-windows-azure.aspx then you can modify the setup.cmd file to install your pre-requisites (if they support unattended installs).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a startup task in the Cloud Service, and have that task (which could be a batch file or a powershell script) run regsvr32.exe to register the COM .dll's, or kick off the setup.exe or whatever specific installer your third party software uses.

It's a good idea with a Cloud Service to make the startup task idempotent, especially with tasks like COM .dll registration or 3rd party software installs. You can do that by creating a text file on the local storage of the Cloud Service instance, and then check for existence of the text file. If it exists, you know the specific step of your startup task has already been run on that machine, and doesn't need to be run again. This is necessary because sometimes Azure re-uses Cloud Service instances.